# Increasing the width of the graph to avoid legend box overlapping

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following dataset:

> TEST   M1-F3   M1-F3-TT    M2-F2
>
> 000    98.74   97.13   99.84
>
> 001    97.30   98.27   100.00
>
> 002    94.23   97.46   97.71
>
> 003    78.31   98.58   100.00
>
> 004    97.35   99.36   99.34
>
> 006    97.49   98.23   98.42
>
> 006    93.59   99.14   99.41
>
> 007    97.63   100.00  100.00

I would like to plot the histogram graph with a legend box, but it overlaps the graph everywhere I move it.

My code is:

```
clear
reset
set key box
#set title "title"
set ylabel "acc"
set xlabel "test"
# Make the x axis labels easier to read.
set xtics rotate out
# Select histogram data
set style data histogram
set grid y
set style fill solid border
set style histogram clustered
set terminal png
set output 'res.png'
plot 'res.dat' using 2:xtic(1) ti col, '' u 3 ti col, '' u 4 ti col
```

And the resulting figure is:
[image]

How could I increase the width of the graph to include a non-overlapping legend box?
I also try with

```
set key above right vertical autotitle columnhead box
```

but I would rather the legend box was inside the graph.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the y-axis range: `set yrange [50:150]`.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with ALJI Mohamed that changing the y range might be the easiest thing, though it would suffice to set it from 75 to 105 or 110 or so.

You could also put the key outside the graph:

```
set key out
```

will put it to the right outside the plot box by default.  This way you wouldn't have to manually adjust the y range, and the data would be guaranteed not to overlap with the legend.

```
help set key
```

for more info.